# Como puedo aplicar seguridad a mi servicio Restful en c#

Tags: c#, rest, restful

Quisiera saber como puedo aplicar seguridad a mi servicio restful que devuelve datos importantes de clientes.

No tengo idea que hacer y soy nueva en esto.

Comment: 3 cosas a tener en cuenta: Custom header, Bearer Token, ActionFilters

Comment: Y para lo que comenta @fredyfx puedes emplear `Identity Server` como servidor de autenticación. Echa un ojo a http://identityserver.io

Comment: y ni qué decir de HTTPS en todo lado :D

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas caen bien en la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. Las más comunes para microservicios son:

**Bearer tokens**

Basicamente es un header Authorization que viaja con el token. En el servidor ese Token es leído y con el puedes obtener cual es el usuario autenticado.

Para implementarlo en .Net puedes usar (las que yo he usado):

- **JWT:** En su página explican muy bien el funcionamiento. Y se encuentran las librerías recomendadas.
  https://jwt.io/
- **OpenID Connect:** Ellos permiten implementar un poco más fácil todo el flujo de creación y actualización de tokens (refresh tokens)
  http://openid.net/

**Oauth2**

Es un estandar de atenticación que permite por medio de una serie de flujos manejar la autenticación y autorización. Es más complejo que los anteriores y son los que usan Facebook, Twitter, etc.

**Basic Authentication**

Es la más sencilla de todas pero no considero que sea la más segura. En esta debes enviar en un header la información del usuario y la contraseña en cada request. [Acá puedes ver más info](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso_b%C3%A1sica)

**Cookies con Form Authentication**

No te la recomiendo para una Api principalmente si lo que quieres es conectarte a esta por otros medios como por ejemplo un dispositivo móvil o ponerlo en un bus de servicios.

**IMPORTANTE:**
Usa HTTPS, recuerda que en la mayoría de estas opciones los datos de la "sesión" viajan con la petición ya que la idea es que son stateless. Así que no los querrás exponer a cualquiera.